# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle

After running my react native app i got this error

"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 57s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release"

i tried gradlew clean but it dosent work...
**please help**